# Images in HTML keep stacking vertically outside of division

Tags: html, css, formatting, position, css-position

I am trying to create a background image that scales with the size of the division. The images I am using need to be laid out in a 3X3 grid with the corners remaining fixed in size and the other parts expanding to fit the division.

However, when I try to place the images they all keep stacking vertically and not relative to the division they are in.

*The test pattern should have the corners as blue, the edges as red, and the middle as orange.*

```css
body {
  background-color:black
}
#test > #Background_UL {
  background-color: powderblue;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
   
#test > #Background_ML {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
    
#test > #Background_LL {
  background-color: powderblue;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
   
#test > #Background_UM {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
}
    
#test > #Background_MM {
  background-color: orange;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
}
    
#test > #Background_LM {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
}
    
#test > #Background_UR {
  background-color: powderblue;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  right: 40px;
}
    
#test > #Background_MR {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  right: 40px;
}
    
#test > #Background_LR {
  background-color: powderblue;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="width:400px;height:400px;">
  <div id="Background_UL"></div>
  <div id="Background_ML"></div>
  <div id="Background_LL"></div>
  <div id="Background_UM"></div>
  <div id="Background_MM"></div>
  <div id="Background_LM"></div>
  <div id="Background_UR"></div>
  <div id="Background_MR"></div>
  <div id="Background_LR"></div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mrg06afu/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easily with a `display: grid;` on the container and specify the `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-columns` and a lot less code is needed. You also need to reorganize your divs as well to go from left to right then trunkate downwards.  The important code I added is this:

```
#test {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px auto 40px;
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
}
```

Please see this example I made for you:

```css
body {
  background-color:black
}
#test > #Background_UL {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
   
#test > #Background_ML {
  background-color: red;
}
    
#test > #Background_LL {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
   
#test > #Background_UM {
  background-color: red;
}
    
#test > #Background_MM {
  background-color: orange;
}
    
#test > #Background_LM {
  background-color: red;
}
    
#test > #Background_UR {
  background-color: powderblue;

}
    
#test > #Background_MR {
  background-color: red;

}
    
#test > #Background_LR {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

#test {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px auto 40px;
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="width:400px;height:400px;">
  <div id="Background_UL"></div>
  <div id="Background_UM"></div>
  <div id="Background_UR"></div>
  <div id="Background_ML"></div>
  <div id="Background_MM"></div>
  <div id="Background_MR"></div>
  <div id="Background_LL"></div>
  <div id="Background_LM"></div>
  <div id="Background_LR"></div>
</div>
```